# Compiling libharu with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, libharu

I'm trying to compile [libharu](http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page) for Android. In my **jni** folder I've:

- **/jni/lpng154/** with all sources and include files for libpng;
- **/jni/libharu-2.2.1/** whit all sources and include files for libharu

This is my *Android.mk* (in **/jni/** folder). libharu has dependencies with libpng so I've to compile libpng first.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

sources := png.c \
    pngerror.c \
    pngget.c \
    pngmem.c \
    pngpread.c \
    pngread.c \
    pngrio.c \
    pngrtran.c \
    pngrutil.c \
    pngset.c \
    pngtrans.c \
    pngwio.c \
    pngwrite.c \
    pngwtran.c \
    pngwutil.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lpng154
LOCAL_MODULE     := png
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -lz
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := $(sources:%=lpng154/%)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Then for compiling libharu.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

sources := hpdf_annotation.c \
    hpdf_array.c \
    hpdf_binary.c \
    hpdf_boolean.c \
    hpdf_catalog.c \
    hpdf_destination.c \
    hpdf_dict.c \
    hpdf_doc.c \
    hpdf_doc_png.c \
    hpdf_encoder.c \
    hpdf_encoder_cns.c \
    hpdf_encoder_cnt.c \
    hpdf_encoder_jp.c \
    hpdf_encoder_kr.c \
    hpdf_encrypt.c \
    hpdf_encryptdict.c \
    hpdf_error.c \
    hpdf_ext_gstate.c \
    hpdf_font.c \
    hpdf_font_cid.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_base14.c \
    hpdf_fontdef.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_cid.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_cns.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_cnt.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_jp.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_kr.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_tt.c \
    hpdf_fontdef_type1.c \
    hpdf_font_tt.c \
    hpdf_font_type1.c \
    hpdf_gstate.c \
    hpdf_image.c \
    hpdf_image_png.c \
    hpdf_info.c \
    hpdf_list.c \
    hpdf_mmgr.c \
    hpdf_name.c \
    hpdf_namedict.c \
    hpdf_null.c \
    hpdf_number.c \
    hpdf_objects.c \
    hpdf_outline.c \
    hpdf_page_label.c \
    hpdf_page_operator.c \
    hpdf_pages.c \
    hpdf_real.c \
    hpdf_streams.c \
    hpdf_string.c \
    hpdf_u3d.c \
    hpdf_utils.c \
    hpdf_xref.c \
    hpdf_pdfa.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/lpng154 \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libharu-2.2.1/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libharu-2.2.1/src

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lz  -lm
LOCAL_MODULE    := haru
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(sources:%=libharu-2.2.1/src/%)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := z png

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When i run *ndk-buid* the compiler stops when trying to compile the file *hpdf_image_png.c* following with many errors like those:

```
.../src/hpdf_image_png.c: In function 'ReadPngData_Interlaced':
.../src/hpdf_image_png.c:113: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
.../src/hpdf_image_png.c:118: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
.../src/hpdf_image_png.c:119: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
.../src/hpdf_image_png.c:129: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
...
...
```

I guess ndk-build cannot find *png.h* ...how may I help the compiler to find the header ?

If in my Android.mk I add the flag:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DLIBHPDF_HAVE_NOPNGLIB
```

before the two rows:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lz  -lm
LOCAL_MODULE    := haru
...
```

and run *ndk-build* everithing compile fine...but I will miss the png embedding in libharu.

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in libharu when compiling with libpng 1.5.

You can apply this patch:
https://github.com/tony2001/libharu/commit/e5bf8b01f6c3d5e3fe0e26ac5345e0da10c03934

Answer (score 1):

because you miss the file "pnglibconf.h",you can find it in the lpng/scripts/pnglibconf.h.prebuilt, 
just rename the pnglibconf.h.prebuilt as pnglibconf.h，then add to the folder lpng.
you also need modify the file:hpdf_image_png.c, add this line:#include pnginfo.h after #include png.h.
that's all, I believe you can success.

Answer (score 0):

I use the answer from jimtoner.
It almost right. But in my situation(lpng 1.6.3), I also need to modify the file:hpdf_image_png.c, add #include  after #include .
And it succeeds!